# why backslash(\) in a string is giving error in console

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, console

i have a string like

```
"C:\projects\cisco\iwan_staging_enc\enterprise-network-controller\ui-plugins\iwan"
```

when i paste into `console` and press enter, it is giving following error as

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid Unicode escape sequence
```

whats wrong here

Thanks

nageshwar

Comment: The \backslash is an escape character.

Comment: means i didnt get you

Comment: you need to use two backslashes for it to be accepted as a backslash: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation

Comment: @NageshwarReddy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since backslash is an escape character your string should be modified to:

```
"C:\\projects\\cisco\\iwan_staging_enc\\enterprise-network-controller\\ui-plugins\\iwan"
```

Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation

Comment: how can i modify it, whatever i do on that string, its giving that error

Comment: You will need the string to be escaped when being fed into javascript as far as I know. Might have alternate solutions but I am currently not aware of those.

Answer (score 1):

The `\u` is the start of a unicode escape sequence, in your string you have a `\u` not followed by four hex numbers which is the format of unicode escape sequence `\uxxxx`. See

```
"C:\projects\cisco\iwan_staging_enc\enterprise-network-controller\u0050i-plugins\iwan"
```

`\u0050` id `P`

Also there there are other types of escapes, so for instance if you had a `\n` somewhere in there you would get a newline

```
"C:\new projects\cisco\iwan_staging_enc\enterprise-network-controller\u0050i-plugins\iwan"
```

So if you do not want avoid these escape sequences escape the `\`s in the string with a slash before it.

```
"C:\\projects\\cisco\\iwan_staging_enc\\enterprise-network-controller\\ui-plugins\\iwan"
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but if the string is dynamic one, how can i Change single backslash to double backslash

Comment: This is only relevant for string literals, i.e. when you type it out in code. If the  string comes from some other source this escaping is not necessary.