# trying to remove \u from ("\uf2bb"- font awesome icon). so that i can get "f2bb"

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2

I am trying to remove \u from "\uf2bb" and i tried using "replace()" method to replace \u with ""(empty string) but same string returns as result of "replace()" which i tried on given string.

I have tried below given solutions but none of them returned what i want.

please guide me how can i get string without escape character. any suggestions is most welcomed.
thanks in advance.

```
   let sample = "\uf2bb";
   sample.replace("u",""); // it returns "\uf2bb"
or sample.replace("\u",""); // SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence
or sample.replace(/\\/g,""); // same string as "\uf2bb"
```

Comment: No. In the first line, the `\uf2bb` is just the way the character is represented in the source. The sequence "\u" does not actually occur in the string, and the JavaScript code sees only a single character with value hex F2BB.

Comment: i got it, i was trying to check character at certain index as sample.charAt(0) and yes it treats it as a single character and returns whole string and sample.charAt(1) as " ", isn't there a way to deal with characters ??

Comment: `\u` is a unicode escape sequence. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641297/1188322 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722295/why-backslash-in-a-string-is-giving-error-in-console

Comment: @kiranvj good explanation anna, but i tried using "\\" to treat as single too but anyhow 
"codePointAt(0).toString(16)" this is really helpful

Comment: `let sample = "\\uf2bb";   sample.replace("\\u","");` should have worked for you, anyway good that you have a solution.

Comment: @kiranvj that would have work but i am not receiving it as "\\uf..." it's as a unicode character so got to work that way

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like that:

```
sample.codePointAt(0).toString(16)
```

[Reading on `codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)

Comment: This will only return the code for the first character in the string.

Comment: @MrLister correct but for my case unicode is treated as a single character at index 0, so this is working very fine for me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot replace \u with anything because it's not a part of the string. This is just an indicator for a single character in your string with unicode 0xf2bb

You can replace all unicode characters with their codes like this:

```
sample.replace(/[\u0100-\uffff]/g, x => x.codePointAt(0).toString(0x10))
```

`[\u0100-\uffff]` will match any unicode character with codes between 0100 and FFFF. Anything below 0100 is a standard ASCII character. Lambda will replace this character with its code

Comment: your solution is pretty correct and as same as "adam's" answer but in adam's answer we are not supposed to expect that we are handling only \u type characters, his answer is capable of converting any \escape character.

I am not saying your answer is wrong but yeah it's helpful where we are receiving different types of \escape characters and we only want to replace \u type, 

but appreciated friend you did a very good job, thanks again

Comment: @MrLister good point. Codes for font awesome are here https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet I think it's same to assume that they just start from "f000"

Comment: @anantvikramSingh yes, here you can also specify the range of characters you want to convert (0000-ffff is the full range) or you can simply put a dot "." to convert everything

Comment: @anantvikramSingh Again, the characters in the string are not identified as "\u" type characters, the \u notation is just how you can write them in the source. You can also write `"\u0041"` for an A, but to the JavaScript program it will just be an A. Now Adam's solution will also replace "A" with "0041"; is that what you want?

Comment: @MrLister ahhh got you, what you were trying to explain, thanks for explanation